# JQuery pass the value from a radial to a select menu on click.

Tags: jquery, html

I want to pass the value from a radial to a select menu on click.

```
<input type="radio" name="option[229]" value="23" id="option-value-23">
<input type="radio" name="option[229]" value="24" id="option-value-24">

<select name="option[229]" id="option-value-17">
 <option value="23">Barcelona Orange</option>
 <option value="24">Chateau Grey</option>
</select>
```

So for example when I click

```
<input type="radio" name="option[229]" value="24" id="option-value-24">
```

It changes the select menu to (Both fields are on the same page)

```
<select name="option[229]" id="option-value-17">
 <option value="23">Barcelona Orange</option>
 <option value="24" SELECTED>Chateau Grey</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone assist? Cannot seem to find anything to help.

Thank you so much in advance for your direction

Stu

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$("input:radio").change(function() {
   $("#option-value-17").val(this.value);
});
```

And vice-versa

```
$("#option-value-17").change(function() {
    $("input:radio[value=" + this.value + "]").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CB4Nn/2

Comment: Really that simple, my word I was well over complicating... thank you so much.

Comment: Any way to add a visa versa aswell so if either one are clicked it would update the other?

Comment: Always, 1 sec, updating

Comment: @Stuart -- Added answer and fiddle

Answer (score 0):

When you click the radio button, set the select value to the value of the element clicked.

```
$("#option-value-24").on("click", function() {
    $("#option-value-17").val($(this).val());
});
```

You can add the other radio button manually, by changing the selector to `23` instead of `24`, or you can use `input[radio]` to select ALL radio buttons.

See this fiddle for an example

http://jsfiddle.net/RUJodan/xXEYj/

Comment: Doesn't change the select menu like the first answer from tymeJV

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value property of your select.

```
$("input:radio").change(function() {
   document.getElementById("option-value-17").value  = this.value ;
});
```

Comment: Already using jQuery, just use `$("#ID")` rather than the whole `document.getElementById`

Comment: Why are you switching to pure javascript inside of a jQuery call?

Comment: @RUJordan This will be faster than `$()`. you can use jquery to set value if there are more elements in the selectior, with vanilla you will have to loop through

Comment: Do you really think speed is a factor here? You're not wrong, though.

Comment: @tymeJV please see  the above comment.

Comment: @RUJordan speed can be a factor right, when you can write something faster what is wrong... I mean it depends on perspective as well. I believe more like you can use the selector especially for the id selectior go with vanilla, no need to jquery overhead.

Comment: @user2253634 -- I suppose. By how much faster tho? Is it going to impact performance in a noticeable amount?

Comment: @tymeJV as i said it is a perspective and a habit.... what if you want to select the value of many ids in the same...